# NullPointerException when adding keys in BloomFilter

Tags: java, hadoop, nullpointerexception, key

I used the hadoop apache to create a counting Bloom Filter. However I get a NullPointerException when I am trying to add keys in it. I tried to change the class structure in many ways but still I get the same result.
Here is the code I did:

```
package package_name;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Iterator;

  import org.apache.hadoop.util.bloom.*;

public class CBF {
public static CountingBloomFilter CBF = new CountingBloomFilter();
public static void countingFilter (ArrayList<byte[]> CBF_Keys) throws IOException{


CBF_Keys= Keys.keyStringArray;

 Iterator<byte[]> iter = CBF_Keys.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    byte[] temp = iter.next();

  Key hadoop_key = new Key(temp, 2.0);

   CBF.add(hadoop_key);
}

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is `CBF = new CountingBloomFilter()`. We should use `CountingBloomFilter(int vectorSize, int nbHash, int hashType)` instead [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/bloom/CountingBloomFilter.html#CountingBloomFilter%28int,%20int,%20int%29), otherwise the `HashFunction` will not be constructed in parent class `Filter`.